# Process.Start() given an Object reference not set to an instance of an object after

Tags: c#, process

I'm in to a loop defined dynamically the function that will run onClick of control.

the function is the following:

```
   public static void TryOpenFile(string filename, EventHandler callback)
        {

                Process proc;
                proc = Process.Start(filename);

             if (callback != null)
                {
                    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    proc.Exited += (a, b) =>
                        {
                            callback(a, b);
                        };
                }
}
```

And then:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfControls; i++)
{

            controlImg.SetFileToOpen(file, 
                delegate
                {
                    //exited!
                });

}
```

Comment: use Process.WaitForExited or similar method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for this overload of Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) explains what is happening (emphasis mine):

> Use this overload to start a process resource by specifying its file
>   name. The overload associates the resource with a new Process
>   component. **If the process is already running, no additional process
>   resource is started.** Instead, the existing process resource is reused
>   and no new Process component is created. **In such a case, instead of
>   returning a new Process component, Start returns null to the calling
>   procedure.**

A new process may not be started if you are using ShellExecute to start a file using it's association, rather than running an executable.  For instance, if `filename` is (for example) "C:\Test.xls", it might start Excel.  But if Excel was already running, it might open the file in the existing running instance, rather than starting a new process.  In that case, the value of `proc` would be null.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I fixed this problem. But I have a problem with the events now.. check out my update question please.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your filename points to an already running process.  As per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Diagnostics.Process
>
> A new Process component
> that is associated with the process resource, or **null**, if no process
> resource is started (for example, if an existing process is reused).

**Update:** If your filename is a bad filename, it will obviously throw an Exception.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I fixed this problem. But I have a problem with the events now.. check out my update question please.